# Resizeable Components in Flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, custom-component

I am using this resizable components in flex having "handles" to drag and resize them.

http://www.rogue-development.com/blog2/2007/05/first-look-at-a-flex-component-to-resize-on-screen-objects/

But additional feature of **deleting the selected components** is not present.

I tried but didn't know how to delete the selected components ?

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a component from it's parent using the [removeChild()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChild%28%29) method, or if you're dealing with a spark component the [removeElement()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Group.html#removeElement%28%29) method.  Conceptually like this:

```
myParentContainer.removeChild(myChild);
// remove event listeenrs for mychild;
myChild = null;
```